# WSO2 Identity Server - IDP Federation with OpenID - Trace and Log Feature?

Tags: wso2, openid, identity

What are the debug options available at the WSO2 Identity server to trace the Identity Federation (outbound) using OpenID protocol? Are there parameters available at the log4j.properties, or service configurations that enables tracing under WSO2 Rel 5.1?

Even when the Identity Provider is configured to run with a federated lookup connecting to a remote Idp, the server is only validating locally registered accounts. Having a debug trace feature inside the server would be helpful to track the message routing and flow.

Configuration Details for Outbound Identity Federation:

```
Identity Provider Name: extbasicws01_openid
Display Name: extbasicws01_openid
Description: OpenID real for SSO

Federated Authenticators - OpenID Configuration  
Federation Hub Identity Provider: checked
Home Realm Identifier: travelocity.com 
Certificate:  Public key PEM downloaded from central IdP 
Alias (default URL):    

Enabled OpenID - checked
Default - Specifies if OpenD is the default 
OpenID server URL: central IDP URL 
User ID found in 'claimed_id' - checked
Additional Query Parameters - blank
```

Any update on this topic? Still watching for a trace option to better track the federated mode in outbound connections, specially when using the OpenID standard. Currently testing with the Travelocity.com client and openid login. Local authentication with WSO2 Identities are answering, but outbound authentications are not sending a redirect to the external IdP. Any hints how to update the WSO2 Identity provider configuration to activate the federated mode with OpenID?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in the {IS_HOME}/repository/conf/log4j.properties file to enable debug logs for OpenID.

log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.openid=DEBUG